# Ranks of block matrices implication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, control-theory, systems-theory

For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such that $rank[A\hspace{2mm}B]=n$ do we necessarily have $rank[A^k\hspace{2mm}B\hspace{2mm}AB\hspace{2mm}\dots\hspace{2mm}A^{k-1}B]=n$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$?

After some random matrix generation in MATLAB, I'm pretty sure that it is true. In trying to prove it, I was hoping to be able to take a shortcut by proving that $rank[A\hspace{2mm}B]=n$ implies $rank[A^k\hspace{2mm}B]=n$ or $rank[B\hspace{2mm}AB\hspace{2mm}\dots\hspace{2mm}A^{k-1}B]=n$ but a counterexample to both is given by taking
$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,
$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $k=2$.

Both hints and outright proofs are welcome.

Comment: @BenGrossmann if you look carefully, $[A, B]$ is not a submatrix of the matrix the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is true and I'll give a general sketch. If $\mathrm{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix} = n$ then the image of $\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}$ is $\mathbb{R}^n.$ It follows that $$\mathrm{im} \begin{bmatrix}A^2 & A B\end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{im}\, A\,\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}$$ is just the image of $A.$ From this you should be able to conclude that
$$
\mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} A^2 & B & A B \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} B & A B & A^2\end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} B & A \end{bmatrix},
$$
which establishes the base case.
This fact can then be used to establish the complete statement by making the following observation,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} A^k & B & A B & \cdots & A^{k-2} B & A^{k-1} B \end{bmatrix}
&=
\mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} B & A B & \cdots & A^{k-2} B & A^{k-1} B & A^k \end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\mathrm{im}\begin{bmatrix} B & A B & \cdots & A^{k-2} B & A^{k-1} \begin{bmatrix} B & A \end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, No, this should not require the invertibility of $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, for clarity, I am using $\mathrm{im} Q R = Q \mathrm{im} R$ and $\mathrm{im} [\begin{array}{c|c} Q & R \end{array}] = \mathrm{im} Q + \mathrm{im} R.$

Comment: Just to ensure that I understand your answer completely, am I correct in thinking that $A\text{im}[A\hspace{2mm} B]=\text{im}A$ since $\text{im}[A\hspace{2mm} B]=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @smoking_huge_doinks correct, essentially using the definition of the image.